# Why does Google App Engine append a path to my 'continue' location during login?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

I'm using a very simple GAE instance from a Greasemonkey script. This worked fine for the last months, but now a path is appended to the final 'continue' location, which breaks the login process for me.

The basic workflow, under the assumption that the user is logged into his Google Account, but his token for the GAE instance has timed out:

1. User opens page A with the GM script installed.
2. The GM script runs and tries to access the GAE instance with a GM_xmlhttpRequest().
3. The GAE instance returns "login_needed|<loginurl>". The GM script extracts the loginurl and sets `window.location` on it.
4. The user is redirected to the loginurl and eventually back to A. However, this time, actual data is returned by the GM_xmlhttpRequest().

The last step no longer works, as the user is now redirected to the loginurl **plus some**, which gives a 404 on the target site.

The GAE code is just about half a screen of code. The authentication relevant code is this:

```
if not users.get_current_user():
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.out.write('login_needed|'+users.create_login_url(self.request.get('uri')))
```

The sequence of requests is as follows, all caused by redirects:

- GET *https://mygaeinstance.appspot.com/?uri=https://targetsite.com/*
- GET *https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://targetsite.com/&ltmpl=gm&ahname=MyGAEInstance&sig=<some sig>*
- GET *https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Ftargetsite.com%2F&pli=1&auth=<some base64 auth token>*
- GET *https://targetsite.com/_ah/conflogin?state=<some base64 state>*

targetsite.com doesn't like that path and as you can see, it wasn't in the initial 'continue' argument passed to appengine.google.com, which was just "https://targetsite.com/". What did I do wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: All the URLs you list are for internal App Engine URLs. Where does it get redirected to targetsite.com?

Comment: The User API in GAE is for authenticating users in the GAE website. Why do you redirect users to another website?

Comment: @NickJohnson: The redirection back to targetsite.com is part of the [create_login_url()](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions.html#create_login_url) call, what I call the 'continue', they call it 'dest_url'. It's where GAE redirects after the login is complete. If I can't figure out why this has suddenly stop working, I guess one workaround would be to use that argument to redirect back to my GAE instance and then redirect the user back to targetsite.com using another redirect. So far, I could do without, saving one request/response cycle.

Comment: @olivierlemasle All I really want to do is perform an authenticated  `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` (basically Greasemonkey's version of an XHR). I only need the above redirects if the user's token has run out. In that case, I need to send them through the authentication process (a bunch of redirects), but in the end, they need to come back to the original page the GM script runs on. They are now authenticated and the next `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` does work and returns user-specific information from the GAE instance, which is really just an authenticated key/value cloud store for me.

Comment: @NickJohnson Saying that the redirection back to targetsite.com is part of the create_login_url() was a bit imprecise. It doesn't perform the redirect directly. It just embeds the target URL as the `uri=` parameter into the login URL, which is then sent back to the GM script, which will redirect the user to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recent change to our login flow for App Engine has created an issue whereby a login with a continue URL that's outside the app's own domain will result in an erroneous redirect such as the one you're observing.

We're working on fixing this. In the meantime, a workaround is to set up a redirect handler on your own app. Make that the target of the continue parameter, and have it send a final redirect to your actual target.

Comment: Any ticket/issue to watch regarding this?

Comment: Still broken btw., any progress? :)

Comment: Are there still plans to fix this? Is it on your issue tracker?

Comment: still seems to be broken unless I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

This redirect is caused by an expired auth token. To make it work again, you need to invalidate the token on the client, as described here: [What is the proper URL to get an Auth Cookie from a GAE based Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919071/what-is-the-proper-url-to-get-an-auth-cookie-from-a-gae-based-application)