# App Engine Login Redirect Fails

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, gwt, rest, restful-authentication

On March 1, 2011 App Engine changed its login flow, breaking my app (see the
Google Groups [message](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/21f534e093250b56/9decc6b1eddd9ba6?pli=1)).  This issue also came up in this Stack
Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203545/why-does-google-app-engine-append-a-path-to-my-continue-location-during-login).  The suggested answers are

"have the app perform the redirect. That is, createLoginUrl only works when the
continue url is a url for the app.  If you need the user to be sent to
another app/host after login, then your app needs to do that redirect"

and

"set up a redirect handler on your own app. Make that the target
of the continue parameter, and have it send a final redirect to your
actual target".

I'm asking this question to get details on how to make this work.  My application consists of two GAE apps, a GWT front end and the back end exposing a REST
API.  Here is the current flow.

The user browses to http://my-front.appspot.com/, and the GWT makes a
JSONP call to a http://my-back.appspot.com/User servlet.

The /User servlet checks the GAE
UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser() to see if it's
null.  For users not logged in, this is null, and the servlet returns
JSONP that the user is not logged in.

The GWT code gets the "not logged in" message, and does

```
String login = "http://my-back.appspot.com/Login";
Window.open(login, "_self", "");
```

The Login servlet:

```
public void doActualGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    String url = "http://my-back.appspot.com/LoginRedirectServlet";
    // String url ="http://my-front.appspot.com";  <--------- Before 1 March
    log.info("Auth then redirect to: " + url);
    String redirect = userService.createLoginURL(url);
    resp.setStatus(301);
    resp.setHeader("Location", redirect);
    resp.setHeader("Connection", "close");
}
```

My new LoginRedirectServlet has one line:

```
resp.sendRedirect("http://my-front.appspot.com/");
```

This usually results in a redirect loop, though sometimes after hitting the initial url several times it works.  My suspicion is that there's something wrong about the code near Window.open, but I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks,
Glenn

Comment: What URLs does the redirect loop go through? And why are you using two apps? This is needlessly complicated, not to mention likely impacting performance.

Comment: @Nick Johnson I hear you about the two-app architecture.  I inherited it.

Comment: @Nick Johnson Chrome and Safari stop at appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-back.appspot.com%2FLoginRedirectServlet&pli=... and my-back.appspot.com/LoginRedirectServlet, resp.  I don't see more flashing by---is there some way to track these (Firebug?).

Comment: @Glenn Firebug, or the developer tools in Chrome.

Comment: It's slightly off topic, but be aware of Section 4.4 of the GAE ToS regarding multiple apps working as one: http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html

Comment: @Steve Armstrong  Thanks for the heads-up.  At this stage we can only hope to get that much traffic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Credit due to Nick Johnson for whining about the two-app architecture.  I've never liked it.  I moved war/MyFront.html and the compiled GWT code in war/myfront/ to the war file of the myback project, changed all urls to the form http://my-back.appspot.com/ and deployed.  It worked!

This is just a hack, but it proves the principle.

Comment: I disagree, a valid scenario for a two-tier architecture is where AppEngine hosts a data backend and various other sites (not necessarily on AppEngine) host different frontends for their own good reasons.  As of January 2014, the issue mentioned in Nick's answer to [another SO question in March 2011](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203545/why-does-google-app-engine-append-a-path-to-my-continue-location-during-login) is still not fixed or is being ignored, so we must continue creating hacky workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Window.Location.assign(url)` instead of `Window.open(..)`.

**Update:**

Possible problem: you browser caches 301 redirect (Chrome does it for example). Since your Login servlet produces redirect and if cached this would produce a loop. Try using other redirect code: 302 or 307.

Comment: Thanks, this didn't fix the redirect problem, though.

Comment: Thanks again.  Changing to 302 didn't help.  The non-announcement of the original change makes me doubtful that there is much forthcoming transparency about this issue from GAE.  It seems that the one-app architecture is the way to go.