# Google App Engine User Login causing a redirect loop

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome

I'm having many users having an problem logging into http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/, a web game that uses Google Accounts for login and App Engine on the back end.

Many players have reported getting a redirect loop error while trying to log in. We have one computer in our office that is experiencing this behavior that we can test with and here are the results:

1. The redirect loop error only occurs only in Google Chrome and occurs for every Google Account we have tried.
2. Incognito produces the same result.
3. Clearing cookies and restarting the browser does not work either.
4. Logging into the "appspot.com" version of the game is successful.
5. Logging in using a different browser works fine, as does logging into the same account using Chrome on another computer.

The server side is using Python and self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)). I tried several iterations with python redirects according to other info I found on this site regarding login redirects, but nothing seems to work. (like [App Engine Login Redirect Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451495/app-engine-login-redirect-fails))

Is there something I should do on the server side? My Python code closely follows the user login examples provided by Google. Is it an issue with Chrome unrelated to App Engine's User implementation?

Update - here is an example sequence of events as requested below:

```
ServiceLoginAuth                                    POST 302        Other
CheckCookie                                         GET  302        https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth
SetSID       accounts.youtube.com/accounts          GET  302        https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fappengine.google.com%2F_ah%2Fconflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fentanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com%2Fverify&shdf=ChgLEgZhaG5hbWUaDEVudGFuZ2xlbWVudAwSAmFoIhSfkpps7Sou7p0pDcUggvvv-l0GlygBMhT6m5i8V2EjrED8udVQ6r4Zv7VD2A&service=ah&ltmpl=gm&chtml=LoginDoneHtml&checkedDomains=youtube&checkConnection=youtube%3A199%3A0&pstMsg=1
conflogin    appengine.google.com/_ah               GET  (canceled) https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/SetSID?ssdc=1&sidt=ALWU2ctPyHwOiQrNHkiA%2F7K8edJ99Cfify%2BvvvmKMq1NJed9MhiJ24KelscxzD6XaYmmzTirp3jlKKPe6xa2XkkHR7fR4Gyk%2FiDd%2BO6dbtIns2qkEpSTvzJaQD66SfDKAfpx846QNbu6MsgIcZuSJ5CAILyruSb2eRUW7njEWxVCHtTAeyNWmsLgtyx9kAFjlhE81wgZ5fyqbInld2XSFYC4WyWWjLQPygBhCVLShNqKJ7RaYCJQhcfbNVJOU9CDgzjiH9dtEJACr2Xu0W5JN%2B8pM4d3hcyUcg%3D%3D&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fappengine.google.com%2F_ah%2Fconflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fentanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com%252Fverify%26auth%3DDQAAAIQAAAD6sQNlJFsUQIrUZMw29w8RwHmwQGvP2ZqQdPRsVz0XGRSmoUK3HxEWytjGroJPTHFAWJCr5ryr5SyWu7ASaeOCGrRZF7H0-wNyL81eJM98LcshCd9eAUHpuwPPXxtOpL9Eq72Akl-ZL0tm59J5r3xMWLvYmPz9O6kcS1_9RvSyjOOOFwClziEVOMeO5oufmZs
conflogin    entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/_ah GET  302        Other
verify       entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com     GET  302        http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/_ah/conflogin?state=AJKiYcHh2jBzY-th8sqOLfwzTUHt5baRGtYquOLUPRXHgsg0zgaf052TVjKOpFGqd24XAM3jxKHDtz8-Dhnsmik81XwSAewQ02dBeb3Ey0w7GLSPho6LP-BhjQrKDOEVWnsZNWngekespXIfKj-6y62a9o3ewKzgeRo0mRomykVdlrs6mFsL9LM7Qv3pRS0yaj9aLBScP8gYpzbfWYharYZET3PDqO99pNcxVZrZgbG12UharF-rukhAP4bpCPhBHS3aagvphQhTgHIaSk7maeSwmsKr2-hsbdca5E8F50Gjuorh7oNO12RQU9UAbJdiuZ_P62JfqVlFPB4-BhIowQ0Q2jGrT9Ly8X78xNfKIDigHj8kqamew_9it4sjgkKkwnam10xV8ILBB8S8iptlfQuaXPWkZAi9hMeYYa6-cvvBiHWSVnTsoDQ75AjMwKIepP3zevRpcwmWCA9IF-yB_EViugDhc9u62rZZRwBKch-JtSti-jlnJisdE05EjGCSmdRrYYawoSqZdI_ejQV-o6Ot352O3LypMDDtP3ksc0e8LJt4EkmYznT3FhBCmUymCLB-Sw9xq_rb
ServiceLogin www.google.com/accounts                GET  302        http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/verify
ServiceLogin                                        GET  302        https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/verify&ltmpl=gm&shdf=ChgLEgZhaG5hbWUaDEVudGFuZ2xlbWVudAwSAmFoIhSfkpps7Sou7p0pDcUggvvv-l0GlygBMhT6m5i8V2EjrED8udVQ6r4Zv7VD2A
conflogin    appengine.google.com/_ah               GET  (canceled) https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/verify&ltmpl=gm&shdf=ChgLEgZhaG5hbWUaDEVudGFuZ2xlbWVudAwSAmFoIhSfkpps7Sou7p0pDcUggvvv-l0GlygBMhT6m5i8V2EjrED8udVQ6r4Zv7VD2A
conflogin    entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/_ah GET  302        Other
verify       entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com     GET  302        http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/_ah/conflogin?state=AJKiYcE0J5fwV9X1rnIOD3aGfKV3EfLCsbXtxgXur-Yqgd7dCnhYNI474er3pCDe63i6L0MKv51cSrtanuQhjzPjGOUZbOdBsATDlAcZDdkyfhqlRE5D7nzs5fDFop23odOD-92CLTAhrdBf9G3Q-HC7ItALo5nej2wxD58zxd0XsLQ0BmezsjWNaI_OrPtjb7z5T7yKnIen-D3NZkxq582CwunrMH_vsD4DM2Oj5TWPVpT3LoFw4-aEQCxztjvvTeUmQd9Tn1CD41BhSEfTVAaQ_68DyCtPSJBs1bKkjavPNIfDo1b0XxlkuukqBumTJlfWiwV0HttGu6hEN7eA91KkInyQ42Avq5VcUo7QobVsCxqhih9nfD3YQb5VaT4gDg0exSfF17Idq_gKjOqmPa-08fKp1wqh1ZzztOiMUXWqVTKmMCg4qdyA5y4bHE40VQ_n9xpV3ZrHQLJRmI2sZ06MSZOg3uUJygwCPy8Jndam1Krasa3ILr0IgymhCjs0VoxarOfdTqfV8zSMLshzNv0TXro_7iplMtdETwFsXdw4YXKaDpizQD18-l_iCP0GQEA6RxiNCxw4
ServiceLogin www.google.com/accounts                GET  302        http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/verify
ServiceLogin                                        GET  302        https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/verify&ltmpl=gm&shdf=ChgLEgZhaG5hbWUaDEVudGFuZ2xlbWVudAwSAmFoIhSfkpps7Sou7p0pDcUggvvv-l0GlygBMhT6m5i8V2EjrED8udVQ6r4Zv7VD2A
conflogin    appengine.google.com/_ah               GET  (canceled) https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/verify&ltmpl=gm&shdf=ChgLEgZhaG5hbWUaDEVudGFuZ2xlbWVudAwSAmFoIhSfkpps7Sou7p0pDcUggvvv-l0GlygBMhT6m5i8V2EjrED8udVQ6r4Zv7VD2A
conflogin    entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/_ah GET  302        Other
verify       entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com     GET  302        http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/_ah/conflogin?state=AJKiYcHAxNQQfH71c7VECr-HiYMOnk53-vBka6npDKTcKBmI_p9i6y-_I6IpAlhZkbwpH5KUqoxxvEJimdiMzFMwSrmeuJLCSOB6QN_GRYkdFmc5Skggg-4uNQUmhQcduuDSglNV6kKIQAFjLXh6QngRHmeO6mlsDZ0TyV4zFRjU9cdbvgF7RhKQgDSgRK7hw_UyXsDXDCehdA8b0zSFB0kWpLPgIflokGteTiNve65Q1D4MWwvuCjCMiYhk_ZVSEpvc9-VSuxr4rv5tWCgzU0RaSILQpn6Dasvmb2MrttkGKTp5siP5_WXCtY6tt9iLicCIE5Yz0ZpJgp01_2vxE9kVaHalImgx_uZHW736l9-FKM0Y3yAK-7uPOTAV6CL5UHANaiTVLjqoMTVrnXCDfFsq8PRg70z-D-U2aLGYDXgeqlpKn3oszezHwguyY5WM75TPOJAYCQFs2o1w0v-aomoANBaE8WU2zQ1VkoS8ijQ-udOSReEiDR_o7-DFtvLWlczbl3yORH5Ue2P8o18xCYFdvZJCL-_MltpyaxBI9azP6ngJcz8hu8bxO2sEVmIpzd56jjASfwcH
ServiceLogin www.google.com/accounts                GET  302        http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/verify
ServiceLogin accounts.google.com                    GET  302        https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/verify&ltmpl=gm&shdf=ChgLEgZhaG5hbWUaDEVudGFuZ2xlbWVudAwSAmFoIhSfkpps7Sou7p0pDcUggvvv-l0GlygBMhT6m5i8V2EjrED8udVQ6r4Zv7VD2A
conflogin    appengine.google.com/_ah               GET  (canceled) https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/verify&ltmpl=gm&shdf=ChgLEgZhaG5hbWUaDEVudGFuZ2xlbWVudAwSAmFoIhSfkpps7Sou7p0pDcUggvvv-l0GlygBMhT6m5i8V2EjrED8udVQ6r4Zv7VD2A
conflogin    entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/_ah GET  302        Other
verify       entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com     GET  302        http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/_ah/conflogin?state=AJKiYcE7y4DwceZDUhnq9VjbvCXMntARCwn2O8zGJa-TqJjH1QeTSFEeTsleP20ImaDTYNGNFbzF5ViRZuwAXhBcmv2U5hEq4RImYhb0_W4_BI_XPAUf0xVzI25N1mx4dS1IqMx8l6chimKLMWf0gyNENCl1NYJEVkUzZFwDTOaUg_XvRuuSWH0ptDu4FxiysEgxbO0-IVi8mClgvaa42WgRoLZbTZ7rynsIuiOYcha3PzcJ5Ec0eODl6PiNAGeywOQfjMMofBWczBkmpJZiZ0RBHT9cUa5yIxsE9Acer7pUGdVK1VViOr_ymQyXp1aD06FEa05A2DgaPS9OYOHIH5NgZ1HWB-2ZofhDM4EjfKaP-ULXBhioNfzvvczROCZsXPE0fy4j3Q5364B10hniJ9TGgYytT1xGXVumREtCpEF-7md6VFtsFdCAFjcJ1lo-FQ7hQazrA3t_t7KmZSb-5gGES90yfaODCUClnBkakX5h1OAMBIStlfJoojIR19_8S0VdMs_JBwaMG991u1PjdQMR9rKbuQSmXr5HG98dqA0LbzQ6tlwT22b7_6noQ25JgnjcfVutbyL7
ServiceLogin www.google.com/accounts                GET  (failed)   http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/verify
```

Comment: Is there any request failing? Chrome, goto View-Developer-Dev Tools, then select "Network" tab. Retry the login, inspect the requests AND the URL parameters. Are all params as they should be?

Comment: Possible problem: you browser caches 301 redirect (Chrome does it for example). Since your Login servlet produces redirect and if cached this would produce a loop. Try using other redirect code: 302 or 307.

Comment: I need to check on your first comment although nothing in the URL parameters seemed out of the ordinary. My understanding is that "self.redirect" defaults to a 302 redirect which should be notifying the browser that it's temporary.

Comment: What URLs are you being redirected around? Is a request logged each time the browser hits your app?

Comment: I've appended the sequence of URLs above. "verify" is the name of the page that initially pops up to authenticate the user and will close itself if the user is already logged it. It appears that somehow "appengine.google.com/_ah" is being canceled, so the next time verify is requested the user is still not logged in, restarting the process.

Comment: I also get the same redirect loop problem (in both Chrome and Firefox).

Answer (score 3):

Coming back to this after a few months, I was able to look outside our code and find what's triggering this behavior. I'm not certain how to keep this from becoming an issue on our side, but here's a fix in the browser settings.

In chrome://chrome/settings/content, if the box labeled "Block third-party cookies and site data" is checked, the redirect loop issue occurs. If it is not checked, login works as expected.